# How to pronounce "reacio" as in "El que es reacio a las reprensiones será destruido de repente y sin remedio"?

Tags: pronunciación

How do I pronounce "reacio" as in this sentence?

> El que es reacio a las reprensiones será destruido de repente y sin remedio.
>
> <sub>Proverbios 29</sub>

Comment: Yo iba a decir que queda mejor "sea" que "es", pero buscando la cita textual en google veo que efectivamente el verbo perdido es `es`. La cita es del libro de Proverbios (Proverbios 29). Me permito editar la pregunta, y entiendo que en cualquier caso no afecta demasiado ese verbo acerca de la pronunciación de "reacio" (aunque sí para el sentido de la frase).

Comment: In [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=reacio) you can listen to the word in mexican, argentinian and spanish version.

Answer (score 3):

The word *reacio* has three open syllables: *re-a-cio*, and is stressed on the second one (*-**a**-*). Nothing particular about its pronunciation: the initial *r* is trilled and the *c* will be pronounced /s/ or /θ/ according to dialect.

In this particular sentence, if you speak it naturally as a native would, and as in any case where a word ends in a vowel and a vowel immediately follows without a spoken pause, the last syllable (*-cio*) will probably merge with the preposition *a* that follows ([synalepha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synalepha)).

Comment: there's no accent in the -e-, so -rea- so i think -rea- is only one syllable with an stressed -a-

Comment: ohh, yup, it has a hiatus, there are three syllables: A,E and O togheter produce a hiatus, i have learned something new today !

Comment: @Mike Well, there *is* a hiatus, formally speaking, but if you're speaking really fast it'll come out as one syllable. Not something a language student should try to imitate at first, though.

Answer (score 0):

Supplemental answer to Pablodf76's.

E and A are strong vowels, so they'll be separate syllables.

I is weak and O is strong, so the O will be the primary vowel in that syllable, and the combination together, IO, will sound like the Spanish word "yo."

Since the last letter of the word is a vowel, the stress will go on the second to last syllable of the word, in other words, on the syllable that has just one letter in it: *a*.

You will want to use pure vowels, as one finds in Italian or German, for example.  It will be easier to pronounce if you bring your pitch up a bit for the stressed syllable, and let it come back down for the last syllable.

The last two syllables are featured also in the word "palacio." In other words, they rhyme.

I can see that in your original sentence, with the word "es" missing from the quote, you might think that *reacio* was a verb.  Maybe you were thinking it was a past tense of something.  However, it is an adjective.